# Multiple many to many relationships in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have 3 entities:

- Song
- Artist
- Genre

One song can have multiple genres and vice versa. A song can also have multiple artists and vice versa.

That's why I'm trying to create two many-to-many relationships. However, when generating the Entity clases, the first of the two is always 'overridden' by the second one and no variable or accessors are created for that one..

Here's my yaml: **(updated)**

```
Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Song:
  type: entity
  table: song
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    title:
      type: string
      length: 300
    mime_type:
      type: string
      length: 20
    filesize:
      type: integer
      length: 20
    length:
      type: string
      length: 20
    created_at:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
  manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: Spotaset\UserBundle\Entity\User
      inversedBy: songs
  manyToMany:
    genres:
      targetEntity: Genre
      inversedBy: songs
  manyToMany:
    artists:
      targetEntity: Artist
      inversedBy: songs


Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Artist:
  type: entity
  table: artist
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 100
      unique: true
  manyToMany:
    songs:
      targetEntity: Song
      mappedBy: artistss

Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Genre:
  type: entity
  table: genre
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 100
      unique: true
  manyToMany:
    songs:
      targetEntity: Song
      mappedBy: genres
```

I don't know a lot about relational databases so I don't know wether this is a bug or that this design is just bad in general..

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have always found that the MasnyToMany relations with the automatic creation of the join table to be too much magic for my tastes.  I explictly create the join entity and then use simple OneToMany / ManyToOne relations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally solved this (stupid) issue. Turned out I had to define both many to many under one manyToMany heading like this:

```
  manyToMany:
    genres:
      targetEntity: Genre
      inversedBy: songs
    artists:
      targetEntity: Artist
      inversedBy: songs
```

Comment: This is because yaml does not handle dublicated keys and simply overrites them. This is very good when inheriting configs (see config.yml and config_prod.yml as an example).